# How to override elastic-search routing by a plugin?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-storm, elasticsearch-plugin

Since 2.x, elastic search disabled routing field in the documents.

Due to this, it has become really difficult to specify routing parameter via the HTTP call, especially when the code for doing so is embedded deep in a third party library such as the elasticsearch-hadoop plugin (See [CommonsHttpTransport.execute()](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/blob/master/mr/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/hadoop/rest/commonshttp/CommonsHttpTransport.java#L405-L482) for example.)

I see a couple of old posts that talk about overriding the "routing" paramater by a plugin (See [github/elasticsearch-direct-routing-plugin](https://github.com/dilshanatwork/elasticsearch-direct-routing-plugin) and [hashing-algo-for-routing](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/1392bx1hvf/hashing-algo-for-routing) post).

But I am unable to search for the setting **cluster.routing.operation.hash.type** anywhere in the elastic-search code.

Does someone know if the above option is supported in the latest version of ES or if latest version of elastic-search supports any way to override routing except the URL-param?

I want to completely disable routing such that whatever node receives the batch of documents, should just assimilate it there only without distributing to any other primary shards (its own replicas allowed off course). This will greatly improve our ingestion from storm to elastic-search where the number of ES-bolts is much more than the number of ES-primary shards and those bolts distribute the load equally among all primaries.

We will never search by ID.